# PDO bind field names in SELECT query?

Tags: php, pdo

Why won't this work?

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT :columns FROM table");
$stmt->bindParam(':columns', implode(', ', $columns), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Is there a valid way to do this?
Maybe as straightforward as my initial code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pdo->prepare('SELECT ' . implode(', ', $columns)  . 'FROM table');
```

Comment: Thanks! So the prepare() method always needs its field names?

Comment: Correct, I think ive seen something called bindColumns, though Ive never used it.  Don't think it's exactly what you were looking for.  Cheers.